# Overloaded << operator for ostream, used in virtual functions

Tags: c++

I've `overloaded << opreator` this way:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const Computer& c) {
     for (int i = 0; i != c.listOfComponents.size() - 1; i++) {
        os << c.listOfComponents[i].getInfo(os) << endl;    
    }
    return os;
}
```

where `listoOfComponents` is `vector<Component>`.

My `Component` class and one of the child classes are here:

```
class Component {
public:

    Component() {
    };

    ~Component() {
    };

  virtual ostream &getInfo(ostream& os)const;
};

ostream &Component::getInfo(ostream& os)const {
    return os;
}

class CPU : public Component {
public:

    CCPU(int cores, int freq) {
        this->cores = cores;
        this->freq = freq;
    };

    ~CPU() {
    };

    virtual ostream &getInfo(ostream& os)const;

    int cores;
    int freq;
};

ostream &CPU::getInfo(ostream& os)const {
        os<<"CORES:"<<cores<<" FREQ:"<<freq<<endl;
 }
```

And finally the `Computer` class:

```
class Computer {
public:
    // constructor

    Computer(string name) {
        this->name = name;
    };
    // destructor

    ~Computer() {

    };


    // operator <<
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CComputer& c);

    CComputer & AddComponent(Component const & component) {
        this->listOfComponents.push_back(component);
        return *this;
    };

    CComputer & AddAddress(const string & address) {
        this->address = address;
        return *this;
    };

    string name;
    string address;
    vector<Component> listOfComponents;
};
```

But then, when I want to print it out via `cout<<os;` it prints out only the address (ie 0x6c180484).
But I can't figure out, how to write it to be able to compile it and to get right values...

Comment: Show us the `Computer` class.

Comment: Contrary to the title, I don't see any virtual functions, and only one `operator<<` overload.

Comment: Your `getInfo` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ah...sorry...my bad... I've updated the post..

Comment: Shouldn't `getInfo()` be declared `virtual` also in `CPU`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why is the method that prints to a stream called `get_info`? Call it `put_info()` (with the same return type/parameter) and use it like

```
c.listOfComponents.put_info(os) << endl;
```

Don't forget to return the stream from `put_info`.

And after you do this, it still won't work, because `vector<Component>` holds precisely Components — if you pushes a `CPU` in, it's brutally truncated down to `Component`.

Comment: It seems, that you're right. I can compile it, nevertheless, I can't access that method in `CPU` class :-/ And I really don't understand why....perhaps I should create new post for this..

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
os << c.listOfComponents[i].getInfo(os) << endl;
```

should be:

```
c.listOfComponents[i].getInfo(os) << endl;
```

This is of course assuming `os` returns the `std::ostream` object.

---

With the way you had it, you were printing a pointer, which returns its address (in hexadecimal).

Answer (score 0):

> But then, when I want to print it out via `cout<<os`; it prints out only the address (ie 0x6c180484). But I can't figure out, how to write it to be able to compile it and to get right values...

I guess you are passing a *pointer* of your object to `std::cout`, that gets printed as its address (hexadecimal number).  If you have a pointer, make sure to de-reference it when passing it to a stream:

```
std::cout << *pointer;
```